# jQuery ajax script request successful with no data

Tags: jquery, ajax, request

I have been searching for a while and can't figure out why I am not getting the response object of an ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'script',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://api.netimpact.com/qv1.php?key='+apikey+'&qt=geoip&d=json&q='+userip,
    success: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { //both parameters come in as undefined
        console.log(jqXHR);
    },
    error: function(xhr, code){ 
       console.log('error');
    }
   });
});
```

The response is supposed to look like:

```
[["Tokyo","Tokyo","Japan","Open Computer Network","35.6850","139.7514","JP"]]
```

Comment: what's the error that you're getting?. If you are making a cross-domain called you should check that you have the correct headers in the response

Comment: why are you setting dataType = 'script'???? that looks like JSON to me

Comment: if I set it to json or jsonp, it goes to error with status 0. Jorge, I'm not sure what you mean by 'correct headers in the response'

Answer (score 0):

You might try `$.getJSON()` instead:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

> Description: Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.
>
> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

or switch to dataType JSONP:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback.

Comment: @IntoTheVoid correct he has to use JSONP (if the server offers JSONP)

Comment: tried it with jsonp, still getting status 0. I can see the request coming through in Chrome's network debugger though.. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What is the full result of the response?